# First project ever

Tags: java, user-interface

I am trying to put together a project which displays a keyboard image on the screen, and reflects whichever keys you type on the buttons on the screen.

I'm having a hard type putting the 2D squared shapes on top of the buttons. I believe JLayeredPanes are the solution to put something on top of something else, instead of the JLabel where I've put the image on top. Suggestions are very much appreciated here.

My question is, where do I put the JLayeredPane? inside the Keyboard() class (don't know if this is a class, there is no modifier or return type), or the Main method?

What I have so far is:

```
    Keyboard(){

        image1 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Keyboard4.png"));
        label1 = new JLabel(image1);
        add(label1);
    }

    public static void main (String args[]){
        Keyboard gui = new Keyboard();

        gui.setVisible(true);
        gui.pack();
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gui.setSize(430,180);
        gui.setResizable(false);
        gui.setTitle("What Key");
}
```

Comment: Could you double check your code, i'm not sure this is valid Java code.

Comment: It looks like it would be if it included a wrapping `class Keyboard {}`

Comment: Do you plan to run this code on Android or is it an error in the tags? Because Swing (JLabel, ImageIcon and JLayeredPane classes) won't run on Android.

Comment: @Benoit There was an error in the tag, I wanted to put Java, not Android. Fixed it, thanks

Comment: It is easier to make your own JPanel with paintComponent drawing all. This allows inverting colors of a key, show capitalized letters on shift etcetera. Make your own data class `MyKey` and hold a `List<MyKey>` keys to draw. `MyKey` could extend `Shape` but not necessarily